# virtualenv edits system-wide settings

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I installed a new virtual environment using the following command:

```
sudo virtualenv --python=python3.4 mysite
```

Then, I edited the permissions of the newly created folder:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 mysite/
```

I then proceeded to activate the virtual environment:

```
source mysite/bin/activate
```

The virtualenv was activated with (mysite) showing up before the prompt.

On my system-wide python packages I have django version 1.7.1 installed. I wanted to install django 1.8 to the virtualenv. So, I did this:

```
sudo pip3 install django==1.8
```

But to my horror, it deleted django 1.7.1 from my system and installed 1.8 on the system, not just the virtualenv as I wanted.

I confirmed this by running:

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
```

It returns 1.8 both when the virtualenv is activated as well as deactivated.

How do I install 1.8 only inside the virtualenv, without affecting the system-wide django version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `sudo virtualenv` Use only `virtualenv`

Purpose of virtualenv is to get isolated python environment.

When you are inside virtualenv don't use sudo pip / sudo pip3.
Use pip without sudo. sudo pip is used to install python packages system wide.

So, normal workflow is

```
virtualenv --python=python3.4 mysite
source mysite/bin/activate
```

`pip install <package_name_version>` like `pip install django==1.8`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the environment variables that specify the python / pip to use (especially PATH) are not passed through sudo. Why do you have to sudo anything anyway? Just create the virtualenv as your user, source bin/activate as your user, and run pip as your user.

For more information: `man sudoers` and search for `Command environment`.

Answer (score 0):

dont use sudo while installing djando via pip and also try to use sudo less for creating virtual env and for changing permissions.
i have tried these way and have done it